# Finding relation between angle and length in a kinematics problem

Tags: geometry, kinematics

[image]

The diagram of my kinematics problem is as of above. I am having trouble finding the proper relation between the length $\overline{CD}$ and the angle $\varrho $. Note that the radius need not be 2 a shown in the image, but can be arbitrary. Using some trigonometry I did however come to a solution, which seems too complicated since this is a kinematics problem, and the focus is not too much on mathematics:
$$\overline{CD}=\frac{R}{2}\left | \cos\varrho  \right |+R\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}sin^{2}\varrho }$$
Anyone else have a simpler solution?

Comment: Essentially, you’re trying to express the equation of the circle in polar coordinates. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Circle.

Comment: Your formula is nearly fine: just drop the absolute value around $\cos\rho$ and it's OK. It can be derived from the cosine rule and I don't think there is a simpler one.

Comment: @aretino I cannot just leave it out, since the range for  $\varphi$ is from zero to Pi

Comment: For $\rho=\pi$ you have $\cos\rho=-1$ and $\sin\rho=0$ so that from your formula WITHOUT absolute value one gets $CD=-R/2+R=R/2$, which is the correct value. With absolute value you would obtain the wrong result $CD=3R/2$.